# Do Rare Items have set colors?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently found a set of Rare Boots and discovered upon wearing them that they were a most garish shade of yellow.

Do Rare items have an alternate default color scheme from magical (blue) items, or are rare items simply rolled with a random dye applied in addition to their properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4175548264) discussion:

"...every rare item has a chance to randomly generate as a dyed item, with a random color."

Comment: Do you know if this color can be removed with dye remover, or if it is the items default color?

Comment: @Rachel I am not 100% sure but I would bet yes. The dye would be realitivley pointless as would the rare item itself if they were randomly generating these really ugly rare items. As you said, in your other question, you like to coordinate haha.

Comment: I'll look it up when I get home later. I have a hideous pink chest piece for my Wizard, which is currently dyed blue. I'll test a dye remover on it and let you know if it goes back to pink or not (unless someone else answers this first)

Comment: @Rachel I'll be waiting for your confirmation! ;)

Comment: @Rachel: Why not dye everything pink instead and go for the Pink'd achievement ;)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Emerica The rare item is simply dyed a random color - a dye remover will revert the item to a normal color